# How to write tests for writers / parsers? (Python)

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, functional-testing

I have written a piece of software in Python that does a lot of parsing and a lot of writing files to disk. I am starting to write unit tests, but have no idea how to unit test a function that just writes some data to disk, and returns nothing.

I am familiar with unittest and ddt. Any advice or even a link to a resource where I could learn more would be appreciated.

Comment: you dont... have a funtion that returns a string ... that is then written to disk  .... that way you can assert that you get the expected string back... you want to test lower level functions that you wall off as much as possible (each function does as little as possible) then by the time you are actually writing to dist all you have to count on is that python `open` and `write` work ... which is a safe bet and outside the scope of what you need to test

Comment: Ah, then should I have a test run the parser on a test file and then check that the parsed data matches some strings?

Comment: Is it enough to write some deterministic content to disk and then check the contents?

Comment: @gustafbstrom almost certainly yes based on the question ... but you dont really need to test that the OS can write files or that `open` or `write` work in python, you can just trust that, and its really outside the scope of what you should be testing ... that said its probably an easier path than refactoring into smaller more modular functions

Comment: Cool thanks, but why not write your comment as an answer so I can mark it answered?

Comment: because it is really not answer worthy ... its basically my opinion which I of coarse think is right, but some might disagree, and it doesnt exactly answer the question as posed (refactor your code isnt a great answer :P)

Comment: Well you could always upvote for visibility...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably, the best solution is to split your function into two pieces. One piece to do the parsing, the second to do the writing. Then, you can unit test each piece separately.

For the first piece, give it a file and verify the parsing function returns the proper string, and/or throws the proper exception.

For the second, give it a string to write, and then verify that the file was written and that the contents match your string. It's tempting to skip the test that writes the data, since it's reasonable to assume that the python open and write functions work. However, the unit testing also proves that the data you pass in is the data that gets written (ie: you don't have a bug that causes a fixed string to be written to the file).

If refactoring the code isn't something you can do, you can still test the function. Feed it the data to be parsed, then open the file that it wrote to and compare the result to what you expect it to be.